# Question - Xamarin.Forms 5.0 IOS black screen

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-development

Xamarin.Forms 5.0 IOS shows black screen immediately after the splash screen.

In debug mode, I was able to access the application but when I changed it to release mode and pushed to test flight, both debug and release modes shows black screen after the splash screen, What could be the issue, please help.

Comment: Did you get any error log in debug mode ?

Comment: Nope I did not get any errors in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by u/SandeepMVN on this sub -

https://www.reddit.com/r/xamarindevelopers/comments/ls0mqd/question_xamarinforms_50_ios/